# Issue Drawing Rounded Corners On Custom Control

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-controls, paint, rounded-corners

I am trying to create a custom control that resembles a long rectangle with rounded corners and a border.  It will also contain some text, an icon and so forth, but I am having issues with the manual drawing of the control when added programmatically to my form.

The code looks like so:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Transitions
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class AlertPanel

    Private m_Radius As Integer
    Private m_BorderWidth As Integer
    Private m_AlertType As AlertType
    Private m_Icon As Image

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates a Radius of the control's corners
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>The corner Radius.</returns>
    Public Property Radius As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Radius
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_Radius = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates the width to draw the outer border of the control.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>The border width.</returns>
    Public Property BorderWidth As Integer
        Get
            Return m_BorderWidth
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_BorderWidth = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates the type of Alert for the control.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>The Alert type.</returns>
    Public Property AlertType As AlertType
        Get
            Return m_AlertType
        End Get
        Set(value As AlertType)
            m_AlertType = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub

    Private Sub AlertPanel_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        Dim rect As Rectangle = Me.ClientRectangle 'Drawing Rounded Rectangle
        rect.X = rect.X + 1
        rect.Y = rect.Y + 1
        rect.Width -= 2
        rect.Height -= 2

        Using bb As GraphicsPath = GetPath(rect, Radius)
            'Draw the background
            Using br As Brush = New SolidBrush(BackColor)
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
                e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
                e.Graphics.FillPath(br, bb)
            End Using
            'Draw the border
            Using br As Brush = New SolidBrush(ForeColor)
                rect.Inflate(-1, -1)
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
                e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
                e.Graphics.DrawPath(New Pen(br, BorderWidth), bb)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Protected Function GetPath(ByVal rc As Rectangle, ByVal r As Int32) As GraphicsPath
        Dim x As Int32 = rc.X, y As Int32 = rc.Y, w As Int32 = rc.Width, h As Int32 = rc.Height
        r = r << 1
        Dim path As GraphicsPath = New GraphicsPath()
        If r > 0 Then
            If (r > h) Then r = h
            If (r > w) Then r = w
            path.AddArc(x, y, r, r, 180, 90)
            path.AddArc(x + w - r, y, r, r, 270, 90)
            path.AddArc(x + w - r, y + h - r, r, r, 0, 90)
            path.AddArc(x, y + h - r, r, r, 90, 90)
            path.CloseFigure()
        Else
            path.AddRectangle(rc)
        End If
        Return path
    End Function

End Class
```

Then I call it like this:

```
Dim a As New AlertPanel
            With a
                .Size = New Size(400, 60)
                .Location = New Point(100, 200)
                .AlertType = AlertType.Major
                .ForeColor = Color.Black
                .BorderWidth = 1
                .BackColor = Color.IndianRed
                .Radius = 10
            End With
            Me.Controls.Add(a)
```

And I am left with this:

[image]

**UPDATE**

After some edits to my code as per Plutonix below, I now have the following results:

[image]

**FINAL UPDATE**

Final result looks like below.  Many thanks to Plutonix for all the help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I am trying to create a custom control` You didnt say whether this was subclassing a control (like Panel) or was built as a `UserControl`.  I am guessing the latter based on `InitializeComponent()`.

The main thing seems to be that the standard Border for the `UserControl` is still being painted.  Add this to turn it off:

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
    ...
```

You may want to hide that property so the end user cant turn it back on in Properties.

Also, with wider borders you will find that the bottom border is being clipped by one pixel (somewhat apparent in your image - the top horizontal appears thicker than the bottom one).  Add this to your `GetPath` method:

```
h As Int32 = rc.Height - 1
```

Result:

[image]

Also, `BackColor` is inherited and applies to the entire client area, which remains a rectangle.  You'll probably need to replace that as well.  Leave the actual `BackColor` as `Transparent`, maybe hiding it that property from the user as well, and use a new `FillColor` property:

```
' in the paint event
Using br As Brush = New SolidBrush(FillColor)
   ...
```

Using a `FillColor` property and forcing `BackColor` to `Transparent`:

[image]

Comment: Sorry Plutonix, it was built as a custom control.  I have added your alterations which has fixed the clipping, but not the black border as shown in my example.  It seems to work fine if I drop the control on my form, but not when I create it manually.

Comment: `Dim a as New AlertPanel`... on my Form_Load event.

Comment: cannot repro.  Try adding `.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None`  in your with block when you create one

Comment: Close?  It looks fixed - you have another problem with the BackColor is all.

Comment: Sorry Plutonix, could you please elaborate.  I only have one area where I fill the RoundedRect path with the BackColour.  Could you please identify the problem further.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the backcolor bleed?  Because the Rounded corners seem fixed.  For the color, you'll need to use a new property like FillColor.  BackColor is inherited and applies to the entire client area which is square.  Use a custom prop and it goes away as in my newer picture

Comment: Ironically, I was actually just adding that in as you replied.  Thank you so much for all your help!  Greatly appreciated.  I have updated my original post to show the end result.  Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

Public Sub ctrlCornerBorder(ctrl As Control, CurveSize As Integer)

```
    Try

        Dim p As New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath

        p.StartFigure()
        p.AddArc(New Rectangle(0, 0, CurveSize, CurveSize), 180, 90)
        'p.AddLine(CurveSize, 0, ctrl.Width - CurveSize, 0)

        p.AddArc(New Rectangle(ctrl.Width - CurveSize, 0, CurveSize, CurveSize), -90, 90)
        'p.AddLine(ctrl.Width, CurveSize, ctrl.Width, ctrl.Height - CurveSize)

        p.AddArc(New Rectangle(ctrl.Width - CurveSize, ctrl.Height - CurveSize, CurveSize, CurveSize), 0, 90)
        'p.AddLine(ctrl.Width - 40, ctrl.Height, 40, ctrl.Height)

        p.AddArc(New Rectangle(0, ctrl.Height - CurveSize, CurveSize, CurveSize), 90, 90)
        p.CloseFigure()

        ctrl.Region = New Region(p)
        p.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Try
```

Put This As A Class file And call Like This as Follows...

ctrlCornerBorder(pnlList, 15).

Here ctrlCornerBorder is our Class File name and pnlList As our Panel Name And 15 is value to be change as per your need to make curvy edge on panel...

Answer (score 0):

I got rounded corners on a button control using a function that's called during the paint event.

1. Must have visual studio, create a new project
2. Select a new windows form as your new project
3. Add 2 x buttons to the form
4. Double click anywhere on the form to open up the code window
5. Delete all of the code, including the `Form1` sub headers, and paste in the below

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D


Public Class Form1

    Public Sub buttonBorderRadius(ByRef buttonObj As Object, ByVal borderRadiusINT As Integer)
        Dim p As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()
        p.StartFigure()
        'TOP LEFT CORNER
        p.AddArc(New Rectangle(0, 0, borderRadiusINT, borderRadiusINT), 180, 90)
        p.AddLine(40, 0, buttonObj.Width - borderRadiusINT, 0)
        'TOP RIGHT CORNER
        p.AddArc(New Rectangle(buttonObj.Width - borderRadiusINT, 0, borderRadiusINT, borderRadiusINT), -90, 90)
        p.AddLine(buttonObj.Width, 40, buttonObj.Width, buttonObj.Height - borderRadiusINT)
        'BOTTOM RIGHT CORNER
        p.AddArc(New Rectangle(buttonObj.Width - borderRadiusINT, buttonObj.Height - borderRadiusINT, borderRadiusINT, borderRadiusINT), 0, 90)
        p.AddLine(buttonObj.Width - borderRadiusINT, buttonObj.Height, borderRadiusINT, buttonObj.Height)
        'BOTTOM LEFT CORNER
        p.AddArc(New Rectangle(0, buttonObj.Height - borderRadiusINT, borderRadiusINT, borderRadiusINT), 90, 90)
        p.CloseFigure()
        buttonObj.Region = New Region(p)
    End Sub



    Private Sub Button1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Button1.Paint
        buttonBorderRadius(sender, 25)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Button2.Paint
        buttonBorderRadius(sender, 50)
    End Sub


End Class
```

Calling the function `buttonBorderRadius(sender, 50)` means you can set different borderRadius's for individual buttons. 
And because it uses the object, you can apply the same function to pictureboxes, and other controls (not all though).

So you can set a 10 pixel border radius with `buttonBorderRadius(sender, 10)`
and a 50 pixel radius like this `buttonBorderRadius(sender, 50)`
just change the integer as the 2nd argument in the function,
and the 1st argument has to be the object variable.